# Android app bundle: What are the chances for resource not resolved exception?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I have an app published on Google Play, now I want to optimize my future releases by making use of android app bundle.

I managed to create .abb and uploaded the same in play beta and it works fine in all of my available devices.

Now my concern is, consider below scenario

I have a resource sample_img.png, and I added different resolution of same image in following folder drawable-hdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi

Suppose I missed out to add corresponding resolution of sample_img.png in drawable-xhdpi. What happens the .abb installs on a device which comes under drawable-xhdpi. Will the app throw resource not resolved error ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't throw an exception. The generation of APK is smarter and the xhdpi APK will include the resource with the closest density (following the same logic as the Android platform).

In other words, the `xhdpi` split APK doesn't correspond to `xhdpi` images only, but correspond to images that would be loaded by the Android platform on an `xhdpi` device.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.